# SQL create variable over columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that is becoming repetitive with the summation of the same columns. What I would like to do is create a variable so that my code does not become unnecessarily cluttered.
A trivial example:

```
SELECT 
    (a.col1 + a.col2 + a.col3 + a.col4 + a.col5)/2 AS half,
    (a.col1 + a.col2 + a.col3 + a.col4 + a.col5)/3 AS third,
    (a.col1 + a.col2 + a.col3 + a.col4 + a.col5)/4 AS fourth,
    (a.col1 + a.col2 + a.col3 + a.col4 + a.col5)*2 AS twice,
    b.sepCol
FROM [Table A] a
JOIN [Table B] b ON b.someCol = a.someCol
```

I would like to be able to remove the need to type the sum(col1...col5) into something like:

```
@myVar = (a.col1 + a.col2 + a.col3 + a.col4 + a.col5)
SELECT 
    @myVar/2 AS half,
    @myVar/3 AS third,
    @myVar/4 AS fourth,
    @myVar*2 AS twice,
    b.sepCol
FROM [Table A] a
JOIN [Table B] b ON b.someCol = a.someCol
```

Preferably I would like to keep this in the same query and not have to utilize a CTE or TempTable if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use that as inner query like

```
SELECT 
    myVar/2 AS half,
    myVar/3 AS third,
    myVar/4 AS fourth,
    myVar*2 AS twice
FROM (
SELECT (col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5) as myvar, b.sepCol
FROM TableA ) xxx
```

Comment: I think you miss _b.sepCol_ column here

Answer (score 2):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT aa.cols/2 AS half,
       aa.cols/3 AS third,
       aa.cols/4 AS fourth,
       aa.cols*2 AS twice,
       b.sepCol
FROM [Table A] a INNER JOIN
     [Table B] b
     ON b.someCol = a.someCol CROSS APPLY
     ( VALUES (a.col1 + a.col2 + a.col3 + a.col4 + a.col5) 
     ) aa (cols);
```

Comment: You miss the _b.sepCol_ column too :)